# How to query a webcam's output formats?

Tags: windows, webcam

How do I query a webcam's output capabilities (e.g. resolution, fps, codec) under Windows? I am okay doing this either programmatic or using a standalone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DirectShow API you enumerate capabilities and media types on the camera filter output pin. This covers resolutions and pixel formats (codecs). This normally does not cover frame rates that might be additionally available via [IAMVideoControl::GetFrameRateList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See also:

- [DirectShow - Get available resolutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/7f0230d4-484e-4752-9d46-24c06bcd8937)
- [Enumerating supported Video Capture output sizes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/70666ade-a426-4622-917a-9d1738fc2acb)

Answer (score 7):

A great standalone (cross-platform, command-line) tool for this is e.g. ffmpeg, the Swiss army knife of video streaming:

`ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` gives you the device list.

Then, for a device name your see listed (e.g. *"USB 2.0 WebCamera"*):

`ffmpeg -list_options true -f dshow -i video="USB 2.0 WebCamera"`